# How can I fix a byte array where the values are off by 4 bits?

Tags: java, arrays, bit-shift, bytebuffer

I have a piece of software which takes values from a byte buffer, and then puts them into several byte arrays using the `Array.copyOfRange()` method. My issue is that my values are off by 4 bits. for example.

I am expecting an array that looks like this (values displayed in hexadecimal, and "==" is just used to say my array is equal to this, I know this is not proper code. Its just for the question.)

```
byte[] expectedArray == {AB, CD, EF, 01, 23, 45};
```

Instead, my array looks like this:

```
acctualArray == {9A, BC, DE, F0, 12, 34};
```

As you can see, it is off by one Hex character (or 4 bits). Is there any way to shift the characters to the left by one to remedy my issue, or is there anything that I am overlooking that may be causing this?

Comment: Don't you think you should be showing your code instead of telling all sorts of irrelevant information?

Comment: It would probably be of better interest to you to figure out why you are getting arrays that are 4 bits off from what you expect, than trying to "fix" them.

Comment: @Kayaman The question if more conseptual about known issues with converting from ByteBuffer to byte[], and if there is a method to shift the characters, so no. I think that what I have given is fine. It is not a what is wrong with the code question, more so a how can I shift by 4 bits question. My apologies if this was misunderstood.

Comment: @Tricky12 The existing code is not permitted to be changed by me, I am simply to come up with an addition to "fix" it. I agree that the situation is not ideal :/

Comment: there is no simple solution.  you'll have to go through and manually shuffle the 4 bits through each byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what you seem to be asking for, it is possible for all values except the last expected value because the `5` in `0x45` is not known. You can use code like this:

```
int[] actualArray = {0x9A, 0xBC, 0xDE, 0xF0, 0x12, 0x34};
int[] expectedArray = new int[actualArray.length - 1];

for (int i = 0; i < expectedArray.length; ++i)
{
    expectedArray[i] = (actualArray[i] << 4) & 0xF0 | (actualArray[i + 1] >> 4) & 0x0F;
}
```

This goes thru each value in the actual array (except the last one) and copies the low four bits into the high 4 bits of the expected array, and copies the high 4 bits of the next actual array item into the low 4 bits of the expected array item. You should read about [bitwise operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can just add 17 to each byte.

```
    Number[] actualArray = new Number[]{0x9a, 0xbc, 0xde, 0xf0, 0x12, 0x34};
    for(Number b: actualArray){
        System.out.println(String.format("%2X ", b) + " -> " + String.format("%02X ", b.intValue() + 17));
    }
```

Output:

```
9A  -> AB 
BC  -> CD 
DE  -> EF 
F0  -> 101 
12  -> 23 
34  -> 45
```

Comment: This works for the given example code. However, I assumed that this was just sample data which happened to have that pattern, and that `actualArray` could be any string of random bytes that needs to be shifted 1 nibble.